# Hibernate naturalID

Tags: hibernate

Hibernate doesnt seem to generate a notnull constraint on a field I marked as naturalID. Is this normal?

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class AbstractDomainObject extends PersistentObject {

 @NaturalId
 private String code;
```

DB Schema: CONSTRAINT SYS_CT_47 UNIQUE(CODE)
There is no not null constraint here.

Answer (score 4):

Checkout the following excerpt from Hibernate's reference manual:

> A natural key is a property or combination of properties that is unique and non-null. It is also immutable. Map the properties of the natural key as @NaturalId or map them inside the <natural-id> element. Hibernate will generate the necessary unique key and nullability constraints and, as a result, your mapping will be more self-documenting.

Note also that by default, natural identifier properties are assumed to be immutable (constant) You can change the default by specifying `@NaturalId (mutable = true)`

Comment: But if "Hibernate will generate the necessary unique key and nullability constraints" and it doesn't show in the example provided, that means, it is not normal behaviour. So what does "yes" mean?

Comment: You're right. My "yes" was confusing... just like Hibernate's docs :) I removed it from my previous answer. How about adding an annotation like @Column(name = "Code", nullable = false, unique = true) instead?

Comment: This inconsistenet with the xml mapping natural id. The xml mapping natural-id does generate the not null contraint.

Comment: @DD. How about filing a JIRA with a sample test case if possible?